# Defining static member of template class in a implementation file

Tags: c++

I simplify the problem. I wanna know why this can't compile:

Error message: `undefined reference to 'Foo<int>::j'`

a.h

```
#pragma once
template<typename T>  
class Foo{
    public:
        int bar(){
            return j;
        }
    private:
        static int j;
};
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
template<typename T>
int Foo<T>::j = 3;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main() {
      Foo<int> f;
      cout << f.bar();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1

Comment: @Fureeish That doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are the cause.

```
template<typename T>
int Foo<T>::j = 3;
```

doesn't get resolved for `main.cpp` as it has no information about `a.cpp`.
And as for `a.cpp` it doesn't create Foo as it isn't used there.

For the system to work, you'd need to add

```
int Foo<int>::j = 3;
```

to `a.cpp` or

```
template<typename T>
int Foo<T>::j = 3;
```

to `main.cpp`.

---

On the side note, maybe new usage of `inline` keyword in `C++17` i what you are looking for.